# Changing global array declarations to use the heap instead of BSS

Tags: c++

Given global array declarations such as `int a[10];` I would like to change the default storage from BSS to the heap in some old code for instrumentation reasons. This partially works:

```
int *a = new int[10]{};
```

Except that the size info is lost which precludes using `a` in a range for statement among other things.

This, however, works and produces no errors or warnings in GCC or Clang with -pedantic. But I don't like using `reinterpret_cast`.

```
int(&a)[10] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[10]>(*new int[10]{});
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>

int a[10];    // zero initialized array in the BSS
int(&b)[10] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[10]>(*new int[10]{});    // zero initialized array on the heap

int main()
{
    // both a and b have the size of an array of 10 ints and can be used interchangably
    a[1] = b[2] = 3;
    for (auto&& x : b)  // and both can use the range based for
        x = 1;

    static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(b), "Not the same size");
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << " " << sizeof(b) << '\n';
    delete[] &b[0]; // unnecessary when just replacing BSS with heap for globals
}
```

The code produces the same assy for the two global arrays. https://godbolt.org/z/fbjzWvnev

Is `reinterpret_cast` unavoidable to do this or is there some cleaner way?

Comment: before seeing this piece of code I wouldn't believe is possible. I agree it looks ugly as hell and I would avoid doing that in production code... but if you really need it...

Comment: @Frank As much as I like `std::array`, I'm trying to change as little as possible in the existing code. For instance I don't want to alter templates that resolve standard array types and sizes.

Answer (score 1):

While this will not work for all possible usages of `b`, at the very least, everything in your posted question can also work with `std::array`.

So you could do:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int a[10];    // zero initialized array in the BSS
std::array<int, 10> &b = *new std::array<int, 10>();

int main()
{
    // both a and b have the size of an array of 10 ints and can be used interchangably
    a[1] = b[2] = 3;
    for (auto&& x : b)  // and both can use the range based for
        x = 1;

    static_assert(sizeof(a) == sizeof(b), "Not the same size");
    std::cout << sizeof(a) << " " << sizeof(b) << '\n';
    delete &b; // unnecessary when just replacing BSS with heap for globals
}
```

Comment: This works though it requires addition of either a new template to get the array size or changing code that gets the array size to use the member function `size()`  And both of these has popped up an apparent bug in MSVC. So if I don't get contradictory feedback in a few days I'm going to mark this as an answer.